# Maven dependecy versions

Tags: java, maven, struts-1, quartz

I am working on an old Struts 1 application. I have added Quartz as I need to schedule a job to run using [this tutorial](https://mkyong.com/struts/struts-quartz-scheduler-integration-example/).

I do however now get a run time error, where it is complaining about the version of `slf4j` I am using.

> 10:15:07,813 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-13) SLF4J: slf4j-api
>   1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding. 10:15:07,814 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-13) SLF4J: Your binding is version
>   1.5.5 or earlier. 10:15:07,814 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-13) SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x. 10:15:07,814
>   SEVERE [org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet] (MSC service thread
>   1-13) Unable to initialize Struts ActionServlet due to an unexpected
>   exception or error thrown, so marking the servlet as unavailable. 
>   Most likely, this is due to an incorrect or missing library
>   dependency.: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:129)
>   [slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:]    at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
>   [slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:]    at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:302)
>   [slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:]    at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276)
>   [slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:]    at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)
>   [slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:]    at
>   org.quartz.impl.triggers.CronTriggerImpl.(CronTriggerImpl.java:67)
>   [quartz-2.3.2.jar:]   at
>   org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.build(CronScheduleBuilder.java:84)
>   [quartz-2.3.2.jar:]   at
>   org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.build(TriggerBuilder.java:101)
>   [quartz-2.3.2.jar:]   at
>   com.travellinck.plugin.QuartzPlugin.init(QuartzPlugin.java:33)
>   [classes:]    at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:884)
>   [struts-core-1.4.1-ee6.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:352)
>   [struts-core-1.4.1-ee6.jar:]  at
>   javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3631)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3844)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [:1.7.0_80]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [:1.7.0_80]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.7.0_80]

My pom file already had this profile using `slf4j-log4j12` version `1.5.8`:

```
    <profile>
        <id>jspCompile</id>
        <activation>
            <!-- TODO: Re-activate default JSP compilation when dependency issue is sorted out. The following happens:
            [ERROR] Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file
            "file:/Users/dawidl/.m2/repository/javax/javaee-api/6.0/javaee-api-6.0.jar":
            org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator
            class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV -> [Help 1] -->
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.jspc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeInProject>false</includeInProject>
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                    </configuration>
                    <!-- Use the Tomcat 6 JSP compiler -->
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.jspc</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jspc-compiler-tomcat6</artifactId>
                            <version>2.0-alpha-3</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.8</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

I added the following dependency to my pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have tried changing the plugins dependency to `1.7.7`.

```
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                            <version>1.7.7</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
```

I have also tried adding the following dependencies outside the `<profile>`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But I still get the above error.

**Question**

How do I configure my dependencies so that I can get Quartz to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest `slf4j-log4j` version and make sure there is only version of `slf4j-log4j`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you mean this? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.30